# Calling a method with parameters in another method

Tags: java, methods, parameters, character

How do I call a method which has parameters in another method?

```java
    public class StackOverflow {
        static String blackListInput = "*[]#$";

        public static boolean isBlackList(String val) {
            if (val == null) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++) {
                if (blackListInput.indexOf(val.charAt(i)) < 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public static boolean cleanseInput() {
            if (isBlackList(val))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clear your your problem

Comment: Please share your code here whatever you have tried. We are not able to understand your actual problem

Comment: I have created the isblacklist method but I am not sure how to call it in the cleanseinput method. I currently doing this: public static boolean cleanseinput() if (isBlackList(val)) return ture; } else { return false; }

Comment: Share your code here and how to call your method

Comment: Please see the added image to question. thank you for your help

Comment: u have to add val parameter to cleanseinput. cleansinput(String val){ if(isBlackList(val)) return true ...

Comment: as per my understanding you don't allow * [ ] # $ this value your input. if user pass the above symbol it will return false otherwise it return true ?

Comment: It should return true if that value is in the user input.

Comment: Okay wait i will update you

Comment: isblacklist method should return true if a blacklist character is found in the input. And cleanseinput should print out a message if any blacklist characters are found.

Comment: Note for future reference: [Please do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), rather add the code to your question as code-formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```java
     public class StackOverflow {
            static String blackListInput = "*[]#$";
            static char c[] = {'*','[',']','#','$'};
            public static boolean isBlackList(String val) {
                if("".equals(val) || val == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                if(val.contains(Character.toString(c[0]))) {
                    return true;
                }
                if(val.contains(Character.toString(c[1]))) {
                    return true;
                }
                if(val.contains(Character.toString(c[2]))) {
                    return true;
                }
                if(val.contains(Character.toString(c[3]))) {
                    return true;
                }
                if(val.contains(Character.toString(c[4]))) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            public static boolean  cleanseInput(String val) {
                if(isBlackList(val))
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                boolean b = cleanseInput("*");
                System.out.println(b);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Other wise we can use Regex for all the alphabet and *[]#$ in input value. i will update you with regex pattern as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Regex pattern

```java
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class RegexPattern {
        public static boolean isBlackList(String value) {
            String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\-#\\*\\[\\]\\$\\s]{0,30}";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
            boolean b = m.matches();
            return b;
        }

        public static boolean  cleanseInput(String val) {
            if(isBlackList(val))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean b = cleanseInput("fsa$assdhsahdfjfjkf");
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it will allow all alphabet and required special character as mentioned in your question. like *#[]$